# To prove this equation for pulleys: F = $\frac{NPF}{Total mass}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Given: inextensible string , massless string.

There is a concept to find acceleration in pulley system quickly. It is that:

[image]

$a=\frac{\text { Net pulling force }}{\text { Total mass to be pulled }}=\frac{m g}{3 m}=\frac{g}{3}$.

We have not written about tension in this equation. I think it gets subtracted I.e like.

$a=\frac{\text { Net pulling force }}{\text { Total mass to be pulled }}=\frac{2mg-mg + T-T}{3m}=\frac{g}{3}$.

I’m assuming it must be like this.

I used this trick in another Q I.e:

[image]

Here , in my textbook it has the answer written for it too.

Total acceleration for this system =
$\frac{4*10}{4+2}$ = 20/3.

I do not think this answer is correct. As I see it , the ‘Trick’ that we are using is also F=ma equation only. There is no tension force included in the formula. Also , if we are including mass 2kg in total mass(at denominator of the formula). Then , why not 2g as well on numerator ?
On 4kg mass which is producing the required acceleration. There is a tension force as well. Why not included that ? To conclude , I’m having difficulty in understanding how is this trick true + I couldn’t find its proof online.

So , I wanted to know how can we prove this formula.

$a=\frac{\text { Net pulling force }}{\text { Total mass to be pulled }}$

Comment: The formula really says: net pulling force = total mass to be pulled times a, which is $F = ma$, Newtons second law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not like that as you are thinking It's correct and it will be

$a = \frac{20}{3} \frac{m}{s^2}$ only. Let's find out how.

First I'll go with the second diagram

For this system the equation for both the masses will be as:-

For the block of mass $m_1$ (which is in this case 4kg)

$m_1 g-T = m_1 a_1$ $----eq 1$

{took the positive direction downwards}

And For the block of mass $m_2$ (which is in this case 2kg)

$T=m_2 a_2$  $-----eq 2$

{Took the RHS direction positive}

Hence we can say that this is the constraint motion so for this, the total work done by the tension in the system will be zero.

Workdone by the tension on 4 Kg block that's $m_1$ will be

$W_1 = \vec{T} . \vec{x_1}$

So the displacement and the tension are exactly in the same direction  so the angle between the would be 180 degrees

And workdone will come out to be

$W_1 = T x_1$

Similarly for $m_2$ block with mass 2Kg the workdone by the tension will be:-

$W_1 = \vec{T} . \vec{x_2}$

$W_1 = -T x_2$

So by the conclusion that the total workdone by the tension on the whole system will be zero then:-

$T x_1 - T x_2 = 0$

Cancelling out the tension on both sides we get

$x_1 = x_2$

So on differentiating both sides two times w.r.t time we will get the acceleration.

$a_1 = a_2$

So this means both the blocks accelerate with the same rate.

So by putting $a_1 = a_2 = a$

By solving all of the equations above we get

$m_1 g - T=m_1 a$

And for m_2

$T = m_2 a$

But in this case mass of $m_1$ is 4 Kg and the block with mass $m_2$ which is 2 Kg so by substituting the masses and acceleration due to gravity in $eq 1$ and $eq 2$ we get

$40-2a = 4a$

$40 = 6a$

$a=20/3  \frac{m}{s^2}$

Now as we know that according to the second law of motion the net force on the object will be equal to it's mass times acceleration. So from this equation the net force on block with mass $m_1$ (in this case it's 4kg) will be $m_1 g-T$. T will be negative just because it's acting in the opposite direction and we have fixed the downward direction as positive and anything which will happen in its opposite direction will be considered as negative.

And on the block with mass $m_2$ (in this case it's 2kg) only one force is acting that's tension so the net force on that block will be only T.

So by just substituting we will get the answer.

And man don't go with any shortcut formulae they are just made to make our life a bit easier (and this is one of it) they will not be valid everywhere just go through the with the concepts and pull out as much as you can.

This system has only three pulling forces they are the tension on both the blocks and the gravitational force acting on block with mass $m_1$ so according to your formula:-

$A = \frac{T-T+40}{6} m/s^2$

$A = \frac{20}{3} m/s^2$

It again comes out to be true

This formula for which you are struggling to find how it comes is like this:-

We assume the single block instead of assuming two blocks with the mass equal to the sum of masses of both the blocks and assuming that the system has only one block and calculate the net force on it, the tension here vanishes out because there are no threads connected anywhere because the system has only one block now.

And the formula comes out to be

$Fnet = ma$

Where here $m$ is the mass of that single block which has mass equal to sum of masses participating in the system.

That is $m = m_1+m_2+.....m_n$ $Kg$

And hence we get

$A = \frac{Fnet}{m} m/s^2$

Hope it will help you!

Comment: The approach here is good, and I strongly agree with your statement "And man don't go with any shortcut formulae".  That is especially true for novices.   Unfortunately, many novices are taught shortcuts only to become frustrated trying to apply them to situations for which the shortcut can't be applied.  However, the presentation is not clear; you took a shortcut yourself!   Your formulae do not have consistent units.   Please do not leave out $m$.   Also, for clarity, do not identify the masses by the number in front of it (2 and 4 in the second picture).  Keep them general: $m_1$, $m_2$

Comment: Yes i've done the corrections as you said regarding the units and the variable representations i think now it's understandable!

Comment: I will read through your answer in some time. Thanks. Shortcut is because I have to give tests & when tests have a lot of pulleys. It becomes to solve it through simple ways. It requires you to need shortcuts since time is limited. @garyp but definitely,I would want to use a shortcut which has a roof too. Otherwise , definitely. You can mess up.

Comment: The way you write things is still confusing.  Your first equation is dimensionally incorrect.    your "4" is a symbol that means "the mass in kg of the 4 kg object".   The unit is hidden in the symbol "4".  Not a good idea.  Better:  $m_2 g -T = m_2a_2$.   and similar for $a_1$.  A third equation is needed, a constraint, this time it's simple:  $a_2=a_1$   Not what you are looking for, I know.

Comment: But It's already known that both the blocks will accelerate at the same rate so I haven't mentioned I think the user is still qualified enough to understand. by the way i'll mention it as you said, you're a physicist I'm still an undergrad so being my mentor i've to obey what you said it's my job. :)

Comment: @garyp okay i've done like what you said I think it's pretty much easier to understand now. take a look please.

Comment: You are a wise student.  :-)      Looks good now.   And yes, it's obvious that the accelerations are the same, and that's a simple shortcut that can be taken.  But I advise taking shortcuts only after the more general procedure is mastered.   Personally, I rarely skip steps, a practice I learned from [Henry Primikoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Primakoff)